SAML Integration with AWS Connect and 3rd Party Application
I plan to create a web application that is connected to Amazon Connect App. Database mysql rds, front end development using reactjs and backend api using.net8. I have already developed a web application that uses JWT tokens for authorization, and I have created a custom user login. However, after integrating with AWS Connect, I discovered that I had to use the Cognito User Pool for authorization because my web site has a different login process than AWS Connect's. I choose to combine both applications using SMAL.
for that i have configure my application with AWS Cognito and once it authorized i have redirect to the my reactapp with token, then i save that token with my local browser as cookie.
now i want once the user tries to login to AWS Connect user need to automatically login into the account without login prompt. aws connect support SAML 2.0 and for user pool we can give Cognito pool
How can I utilize both applications with Single Sign-On?
